# Bad file number in simple main function with pipes

Tags: c, unix, io, pipe, file-descriptor

I am still a baby in C world and I was doing some "system" programming in order to do some exercises when I stumbled upon some error which is obvious, but I can't find the problem within my application

This is the code

```
const int __WRITE_ERROR = 44;
const int __READ_ERROR = 43;

const int READ = 0;
const int WRITE = 1;
const int MAX = 1024;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd[2], n;
    char buff[MAX];

    if(pipe(&fd[2]) < 0)
        exit(__PIPE_ERROR);
    printf("Hello, from pipe: write: %d and read: %d\n", fd[WRITE], fd[READ]);

    if(write(fd[WRITE], "Hello World\n", 12) != 12) {
        printf("Explanation: %i", errno); // <- constantly comes here with errno 9 for some reason.
        exit(__WRITE_ERROR);
    }

    if((n = read(fd[READ], buff, MAX)) != 0)
        exit(__READ_ERROR);

    write(1, buff, n);
    exit(0);
}
```

Could you help me out, cause I ran out of options, thanks.

Comment: Ah, damn must have forgotten this part, well simple global const integer variables of 0 and 1 respectively o.O

Comment: Edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with:

```
if (pipe(&fd[2]) < 0)
```

It should be instead:

```
if (pipe(fd) < 0)
```

The former is passing to `pipe()` the address of one element past of the bounds of the array `fd` (i.e.: the `&fd[2]`).

---

Also, `read()` and `write()` return the number of bytes read or written, respectively. However, if an error occurs `-1` is returned for both functions.

Comment: Pff, silly me, however, now read starts to fail with errno 0 o.O after I start the program like so in bash -> ` ./a.out > xx `

Comment: @kuskmen `read()` return the bytes read, and return -1 if error. Your error check for `read()` is wrong.

Comment: Yes, found the problem will post it here, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

As someone already pointed out first mistake was

```
if (pipe(&fd[2]) < 0)
```

had to be

```
if (pipe(fd) < 0)
```

then read was failing because of wrong conition

```
if((n = read(fd[READ], buff, MAX)) != 0)
```

should have been

```
if((n = read(fd[READ], buff, MAX)) <= 0)
```